# Not able to get values from the yaml file using Mock in Groovy test case

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mockito

I'm writing a unit test case for my functionality using Groovy. But, however I'm not able to configure the values that are available in the class. The values are configured in my yaml file.

Here is my code

```
class UpdateServiceImplTest extends Specification {



     DataSourceRestTemplateConfig dataSourceRestTemplateConfig



    def setup() {
          dataSourceRestTemplateConfig= Mock(DataSourceRestTemplateConfig )

    }
}
```

This DataSourceRestTemplateConfig  class is using some properties, which is coming as null while executing the test

```
    public class DataSourceRestTemplateConfig  {

          @Autowired
          RestTemplate restTemplate;

          @Value("${datasource.auth.username}")
          private String userNameNew;

          @Value("${datasource.auth.password}")
          private String passwordNew;

            // Method to call DB here

  }
```

The above values are coming as null when I evaluate the expression. Are there any other configurations am I missing?

Any ideas would be greatly helpful to me.

Comment: You create a mock for the `dataSourceRestTemplateConfig` class/object. So none of these values will be set. What is it that are you trying to test?

Comment: @second, I want userNameNew & passwordNew values to be available, as these are required to hit the DB in the method

Comment: Is the method to access the db part of the `DataSourceRestTemplateConfig ` class? Then you only need to define what the method is supposed to return. Are you trying to write a `UnitTest` (which normally has no database interaction) or an `IntegrationTests` ?

Comment: There is a method inside DataSourceRestTemplateConfig class, which accepts userName & password that interacts with the DB